# How to set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS without using a path

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, environment-variables, google-oauth

I'm developing a CMS module that needs to use Google OAUTH 2 for server to server applications. According to the [official manual](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/auth/service-accounts) one needs to set an environment variable with the path to .json key like so:

```
putenv('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/path/to/service-account.json');
```

And here is the tricky part. If I'd use it in a stand-alone web application, then there wouldn't be any problem, but since I'm working on a CMS module, storing that file on a drive or creating any kind of hooks associated with the use of this file would pose a potential security threat since I already see how one could sneakily steal the content of the key through the use of another module.

I want to store the content of this file in the DB and the question: is there a way I could somehow set the environment value of GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS without using a path?

Comment: Did you find a solution yet ?

Comment: Not really. I have opened [this topic](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/protecting-a-value-in-wp_options/) and the best solution was an obfuscation of a key somewhere in the code. Encrypting it with locally stored private key is not a solution either. Basically people just say that its the user responsibility to make sure that their CMS is uncompromised. A workaround would be to store those service keys on a service backend. That would solve lots of issues with extra load on user website.

Comment: Depends on how important this is to you but you could have your class that handles the API write a file temporarily by reading out of the DB and placing it somewhere for the use of the class. Maybe add something that adds a part of it from the PHP to the file upon use. Also you should probably just restrict the API to the domains that matter to you and that would prevent theft. I was thinking that maybe you could write it to a ram drive but I don't think it or any of my suggestions would add any real security (aside from locking down who can use it on Google).

Comment: @MikeQ This is the problem. If I store any value in the WordPress DB, it becomes available to any malicious piece of code. There is really no necessity for such measures since the plugin will be freely distributable and everyone will be able to see how this key is stored in the DB. I will of course restrict api use to domains, but my concern is that someone can use service keys for an access to user google services data from other servers.

Comment: Hard to argue that one, I guess I would probably set up a low rent server that could handle a secure SAML handshake and that box can perform the work more security, maybe memcache it so it calls the results only once per image etc.. I think there are middleware products and services out there ...

Comment: @MikeQ I was thinking about giving the users an option to store the key on service server, so that service itself would pull Google data directly and serve the processed results to users (which in my case would not compromise anything)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One can use keyFile key accepted as a config option while initializing clients.

Sample code taken from the offical api doc - https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-php

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Google\Cloud\Core\ServiceBuilder;

// Authenticate using a keyfile path
$cloud = new ServiceBuilder([
    'keyFilePath' => 'path/to/keyfile.json'
]);

// Authenticate using keyfile data
$cloud = new ServiceBuilder([
    'keyFile' => json_decode(file_get_contents('/path/to/keyfile.json'), true)
]);
```

In place of ServiceBuilder one can use any google client.